# How to stop wrapping characters in div? or

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
<div class="moti" id="content">
    Hello World ! What's up ??? What ??!
</div>
<script>
    Aloha.ready( function() {
        Aloha.jQuery('#content').aloha();
    });
</script>
```

Here:

http:http://oo.netii.net/bootstrap/index.php

How can I stop the exodus of characters which DIV ?

I want it to stop writing altogether characters

Because I need only height and width of this

or : How do I pull only from its size?

Comment: Try addin ``overflow: scroll`` to your ``.moti`` class

Comment: just do a height: auto; instead of making it a fix height

Comment: Thank you!
 But I do not want - overflow: scroll 
I want it to stop writing altogether characters

Comment: Ah you mean, when the user typed x characters to fill the box, he should not be able to write any other characters??

Answer (score 1):

As Sergio mentions, you can add `height: auto` to the element's styling instead of making it fixed-height.

However, if having the element fixed-height is a requirement, you can add `overflow-y: scroll` to your `.moti` styling which will give you only a vertical scrollbar once its contents have exceeded the container's height.

[Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/B4uqr/).